# What technology was used in the creation of Ancient Earth in dinosaurpictures.org website?

Tags: 3dtexture

I've been watching this Ancient Earth globe for sometime and got mesmerized by it. It ticked my imagination enough that I wonder what technology was used in the creation of this beautiful Ancient Earth Globe in the Ancient Dinosaurs website.

The link to the Ancient Earth looks like this:

https://dinosaurpictures.org/ancient-earth#

[image: Ancient Earth globe]

What is the technology used in the creation of Ancient Earth globe? It greatly interests me and perhaps, I might make my own graphics with the technology used in the making of Ancient Earth globe...

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to CG. We can't answer what specific technologies were used to create this globe because we are not the developers. Also, which technology exactly are you referring to? The rendering engine/API? Please take a look at our [help pages](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help) to get some guidance and edit your question so that it is not too broad and can be answered by the community and not just the devs. Otherwise, it might get closed.

Comment: From a graphics point of view, creating a globe similar to the one you linked is pretty simple (given you have the data). You should be able to create it with any modern web-based engine or API like WebGL.

Comment: @wychmaster AAhhhhh... I see....I just need to use FireFox (web-based engine) and WebGL (for graphics) to create that Ancient Earth. Thank you for helping me out!....